# Difference between normal UNet and GAN

Tags: conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have a **strict** image to image translation task, with enough given image pairs.
Two methods instantly came to my mind:

1. Using something like the UNet, define the loss function such as the RMSE.
2. Using the GAN family models.

So what's the fundamental differences between these two methods? Will one outperforms the other and why?